# Simple looking matrix limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, matrix-calculus

I am trying to evaluate:

$$\lim_{V\rightarrow {\bf{0}}^{n\times n}}\frac{|\text{tr}(V^2)|}{\|V\|_{op}}$$

($\text{tr}(V^2)$ is the trace of the matrix $V^2$)

Hoping that the limit is $0$ to show a function is Frechet differentiable, it seems this should be the answer intuitively.

I am slightly stuck, my only idea at the moment is

$$\lim_{V\rightarrow {\bf{0}}^{n\times n}}{|\frac{1}{\|V\|_{op}}\text{tr}(VV)|} = \lim_{V\rightarrow {\bf{0}}^{n\times n}}{|\text{tr}(\hat{V}V)|} = \text{tr}({\bf{0}}^{n\times n}) = 0$$

Which feels incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $V = [v_{ij}]$ and notice that by the Cacuchy-Schwarz inequality

$$ \left| \operatorname{tr}(V^2) \right|
= \left|\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} v_{ij}v_{ji} \right|
\leq \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |v_{ij}|^2
= \operatorname{tr}(V^* V)
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i $$

where $V^*$ is the adjoint (conjugate transpose) of $V$ and $\lambda_i$'s are eigenvalues of $V^*V$. (Since $V^*V$ is positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix, it follows that $\lambda_i \geq 0$.) We also notice that

$$ \|Vx\|^2 = \langle Vx, Vx\rangle = \langle x, V^* Vx \rangle $$

and hence by the spectral theorem we obtain

$$ \| V \|_{\text{op}}
= \max_{\|x\|=1} \frac{\|Vx\|}{\|x\|}
= \left( \max_{i=1,\cdots,n} \lambda_i \right)^{1/2}. $$

Combining altogether,

$$ \left| \operatorname{tr}(V^2) \right|
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i
\leq n \left( \max_{i=1,\cdots,n} \lambda_i \right)
= n \| V\|_{\text{op}}^2. $$

Therefore the conclusion follows from the squeezing lemma.

---

Let me also give a slightly different reasoning: Consider the Frobenius norm

$$\| V \|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(V^*V)} = \left( \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |v_{ij}|^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$

It is easy to check that $ (A, B) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(A^* B) $ is an [*inner product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) and hence $\|V\|_F$ is indeed a norm. Now recall that any two norms on a finite-dimensional space are comparable to each other, so there exists an absolute constant $C > 0$ for which $ \| V\|_F \leq C \|V\|_{\text{op}} $ holds for any $n\times n$ matrix $V$. So by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$ \left|\operatorname{tr}(V^2)\right| \leq \| V^* \|_F \| V \|_F = \| V \|_F^2 \leq C^2 \|V \|_{\text{op}}^2 $$

and again the limit is zero by the squeezing lemma.

Comment: Very clever and elegant, though it seems like overkill for original question my limit came from. I will probably accept greg's answer as it was earlier and has a lower reputation, but this is definitely useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $V$ approaches the zero matrix from a constant direction $X$, i.e.  $$V=\beta X$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
 L &= \lim_{V\to 0} \frac{|{\rm tr}(V^2)|}{\|V\|} \cr 
 &= \lim_{\beta\to 0} \frac{|\beta|^2\,\,|{\rm tr}(X^2)|}{|\beta|\,\,\|X\|} \cr
 &= \frac{|{\rm tr}(X^2)|}{\|X\|}\,\,\lim_{\beta\to 0}|\beta| \cr
 &= 0 \cr
}$$

Comment: Is the constant direction assumption allowed? I remember several complex analysis counter examples where certain parametrised paths "broke" the limit, its a different situation obviously but just to be sure.

Comment: You didn't state any conditions on how the matrix should approach zero, so I assumed the simplest case. But you're right, this parameterization may not be allowable. You'll need to tell me more about the context of the problem.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if want to prove Frechet differentiability for a function I simply require the existence of a bounded linear map (which I have already checked) and all directional derivatives to exist, which should allow the assumption of constant direction approaches. So I think your solution is correct.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis, Even for $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ the existence of a linear map $L$ for which $D_v F(\mathrm{x}_0) = Lv $ holds for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is not enough to guarantee the Frechet differentiability. Directional derivatives can only be used to compute the already-proven-to-exist Frechet derivative. (But some regularity assumptions on partial derivatives may improve directional differentiability to Frechet differentiability.)

Comment: Ah, my apologies then, I was mistaken.